# Is it possible to limit SFSpeechRecognizer's vocabulary?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sfspeechrecognizer

I'd like to use the ios `SFSpeechRecognizer` to recognize a closed set of words and phrases. Is there a way to specify these and remove all other possibilities? I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use **contextualStrings** property of **SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest**  to set high priority or to set some words that are not in vocabulary.
For more info look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/1649391-contextualstrings?language=objc

```
  SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest *recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
    recognitionRequest.contextualStrings = @[@"Your specific word", @"short custom phrases that are unique to your app"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot limit `SFSpeechRecognizer`'s vocabulary, but you can fire action only if the words you want are recognized.

When you get your output, you can try something like this:

```
self.recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
    if result == "Desired word one" {
        // Do something
    } else if result == "Desired word two" {
        // Do something else
    } else {
        // Don't do anything
    }
})
```

Comment: That’s too bad. My intention was to make certain words likelier to be candidates, not to ignore transcriptions containing out-of-vocabulary words.

Comment: Do you mean you want a personal vocabulary that contains "special" words like "expecto patronum"?

Comment: No, and SFSpeechRecognizer is terrible at doing that even if it has that feature supposedly. I mean that if I had control over what algorithm they used to recognize words, supposing they had several candidates for a result, I’d want to make some of the candidates non-existent. For example, the recognizer is bad at math terms. “N numbers” yet erroneously recognizes words as company names I don’t care about without any way of knowing what other choices there were. I think there’s no way to guide the algorithm internally though. It is what it is.

Comment: I see... it would be very useful, but I don't think it is possible. Anyway, have you tried SiriKit? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit I never used it, but I remember I read somewhere you could have personal vocabulary.

Comment: It won’t work for my purposes unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and error, the best solution is a mix between Mrsantateam and Giuseppe Garassino's answers.

you can first specify all commands that should be "prioritized" by setting `contextualStrings`...

```
var contextualString = ["hello world", "goodbye world"]
recognitionRequest.contextualStrings = contextualString
```

... And later filter those results in `recognitionTask` :

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
    var isFinal = false
    
    if let result = result {                
        for transcription in result.transcriptions {
            print("Pondering \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
            if contextualString.contains(transcription.formattedString.lowercased()) {
                print("Found \(transcription.formattedString)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Sample code can be found at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio if you want to play with it and test its limits